# Image not appearing in the correct section

Tags: graphics, sectioning

im new in the latex program and im having a problem thats puzzling me... I introduced 2 figures inside a section, but these images appears outside that section.

[image: Inside the project]

[image: Inside the "code"]

Thanks guys

Comment: Welcome and thanks for providing your code, it is very often necessary. For your next question, please paste it into your message instead of an image, so that it can be copied and tested.